# NaN error whats wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have tried so many methods still couldnt figure out why this calculation is not going through, Im using google distance calculate to calculate distance and then calculating fare. any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        Source:
        <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="heathrow terminal 5" style="width: 300px" />
        &nbsp; Destination:
        <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="bath road, tw6" style="width: 300px" />
        <br />
        



        <input type="button" id="calufare" runat="server"  value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()"/>
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Label ID="dvDistance" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
        <asp:Label ID="dvDuration" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="rate" runat="server" Text="2.5"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Fareid" runat="server" Text="Price£  "></asp:Label>

        <script>

            
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 200px">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 200px">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': false });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var heathrow = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4711620, -0.4523710);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: heathrow
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        //*               FOR PRICE CALCULATION                         * //


    





        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
                dvDuration.innerHTML = "";
                dvDuration.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;
                
                var distanceMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
               var rate = document.getElementById('Fareid').value;

                rate=document.getElementById('Fareid').innerHTML = rate / 1000 * distanceMeters;

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Your code puts the text "Distance: " before the distance value. Then your code after that gets the `.innerHTML` back again and passes that to `parseInt()`.

Comment: what you reckon where is the change needed??

Comment: Why don't you just use `parseInt(distance)` instead of parsing the innerHTML?

Comment: still not working, if the editing in snippet is correctly done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not returning a number:

```
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
```

If you use a numeric value for rate and a numeric value for the distance (like [`response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Distance) which is the distance in meters), you will get a numeric answer.

This gives me a result:

```
var distanceMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
rate = 2.5;
document.getElementById('Fareid').innerHTML = rate * distanceMeters;
```

Comment: its working fine for me but i dont know why its not working in stackoverflow on run code snippet